# Custom converter overriding ContractResolver

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to use a custom converter modifying object types as described [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm), together with the [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm).

So the converter is like this (doing nothing here):

```
class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyType));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
        t.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
var jsonSerializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
jsonSerializationSettings.Converters.Add(new MyJsonConverter());
var camelCaseJsonOutput = await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(myObject, Formatting.None, jsonSerializationSettings);
```

But the serialized output shows properties starting in upper-case, so it seems that using my converter somehow cancelled the camel-case contract resolver...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create

```
JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
```

It creates raw json without formatting.
So, you could control it in your own way, camel, Pascal, wHaTeVeR.

for example:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var myType = value as MyType;
    if (myType != null)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("myProperty");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, myType.myProperty); // Using this will allow to serialize inner values with CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
        writer.WritePropertyName("Inner");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, myType.Inner);
      ...
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

for serialize object with camelCase and additional property I will go this way (may be not most efficient)

```
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WritePropertyName("_custom_Prop_");
        writer.WriteValue("Custom Property value");

        WriteObjectProperties(writer, value);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    private static void WriteObjectProperties(JsonWriter writer, object value)
    {
        var myJsonWriter = new JTokenWriter();
        var js = new JsonSerializer();
        js.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        js.Serialize(myJsonWriter, value);
        var childTokens = myJsonWriter.Token.Children();
        foreach (var childToken in childTokens)
        {
            childToken.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful explanation. What I'm trying to achieve is to add a special property to the serialized object when it is of a particular type. Would there be any way to do this (together with camel-casing) without having to manage the whole serialization manually, then?

Comment: Edited answer with example of special property